# can there be a stale EF model in IIS application pool?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iis-7, jobs

We made a very minor change to our Entity Framework Code First model by adding a column to an already existing Entity called "EntityLog". After deployment we verified that the data was going into the EntityLog along with the data for that new column.

We are using WebBackgrounder, which schedules a web based background job as part of the web application and runs every few minutes and detects if there is something to be recorded to the EntityLog and logs it. It has an Execute method which creates an async Task which in turn creates a repository to the EF model.

Around 10 hours after deployment the application started throwing exceptions when the WebBackgrounder scheduler would try to log to EntityLog saying the new column was invalid. The web application itself was fine, and we could trigger actions in it that also logged to Entity Log, including the new column. It's just the Background scheduler that kept failing. And it didn't consistently fail. It succeeded sometimes.

I couldn't really figure out what was going on except from the stack trace I could see what exactly it was trying to put in the Log. It stopped throwing exceptions around 15-16 hours after that and I could see that it had finally logged to the EntityLog.

The whole web application runs under a single application pool. So it's not as if the Background job is running in another application pool. The weird part to me is that the Background job had succeeded in putting other messages into the Database earlier. My question is, could there have been a worker process in the application pool that had a stale DBContext that it kept thinking the new column in the table was invalid? Has anybody else experienced this?

EDIT: I was talking about async tasks provided in .net System.Threading.Tasks:

```
public override Task Execute()
{
    return new Task(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.Debug("Background processing started");
            using (var repository = RepositoryFactory.CreateRepository())
            {
                var cacheProvider = new CacheProvider(new MemoryCacheAdapter());
                using (var managerContainer = new ManagerContainer(repository, cacheProvider))
                {
                    try
                    {
```

Comment: You casually touch the source of your issue: _"creates an async Task"_. Don't invent your own background task system in ASP.NET, it will break sooner or later as you've found out, because of reasons beyond your control. Or so I suppose. Please elaborate how that background job system works exactly.

Comment: @CodeCaster I've added more info.